# Symfony2 - Custom authorization/access control logic

Tags: php, symfony

Our system allows for an unlimited level of nested `Company` entities (domain object), with each `User` assigned to a single company. For any given user, all users assigned to a company in the tree beneath them are rights managed by that user.

Each `User` can be assigned certain security attributes for a given class (i.e. the `ADD` attribute for blog posts) as well as security attributes for an object of a given class (i.e. the `EDIT` attribute on blog post X). These attributes should also be available to any users above them in the company tree.

It seems like this structure does not fit into the default security roles or Symfony ACL system very well.

Creating an Access Control Entry (ACE) to assign rights for every user that has access to an object seems inefficient, and given the complexity of the user structure outlined above, assigning access to all users of a certain role would be cumbersome.

Is there a way to make this fit with a custom instance of `SecurityIdentityInterface`, or should I use a custom security voter?

Answer (score 0):

fosuserbundle will be your solution

[fosuserbundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)

and [symfony acl](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html)

Comment: As I mentioned I don't think ACL alone is a good fit as we'd need to store multiple ACEs for each object due to the user structure. I've edited my answer as I may not have been clear enough. My concern is primarily performance.